# Sequlize is ignoring association alias name in has many

Tags: sequelize.js, has-many

I have the following mapping on PersonEntity:

```
    @HasMany(() => ContentEnrichmentEntity, {
        foreignKey: 'parentId',
        foreignKeyConstraint: false,
    })
    entities?: ContentEnrichmentEntity[];
```

When I query, I want to join/include this association twice.

```
query.include.push({
   association: 'entities',
   as: 'entities' + i, //integer... entities1, entitie2 ext
   isAliased: true,
   attributes: [],
   required: true,
})
```

When the query is generated and run, the alias generated is `entities` for both joins.
expected: `entities1` or `entitie2`

How is it possible to run this include twice or more.

thanks